# Change TabItem CornerRadius based upon TabStripPlacement

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, controltemplate

Does anyone know how to setup triggers within a TabItem, or TabControl, which will alter the CornerRadius of a TabItem's internal border, based solely upon the TabItem's placement/orientation? Here is picture of what I'm wanting to fix:

[image]

There are two groups of tabs you should take note of, the top left one with the text "Cell Browser", and the bottom ones. Looking at it, you can see that the corner radius of the bottom TabItems are incorrect for the rotation of the TabItems. They're inverted, when they should be downwards. Does anyone know how to change the corner radius of the TabItems based upon the tab strip placement? I'm already aware that I can just create different styles for each specific orientation, like one for when the placement is Left, Bottom, etc. However, I'd rather only have one if at all possible.

Looking at the xaml below, there is a border within the tabitem declaration, called simply "Border". This is what I'm hoping to change via a trigger. I just don't know how to access it from the tabcontrol style, or optionally, do the same from the tabitem style triggers and somehow detect the current orientation.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VoidwalkerEngine.Editor.Resources.Themes.Styles">

    <Style x:Key="VoidwalkerTabControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#3f3f46" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid
                        x:Name="templateRoot"
                        Background="#181818"
                        ClipToBounds="true"
                        KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0" />
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TabPanel
                            x:Name="headerPanel"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Margin="0"
                            Panel.ZIndex="1"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            IsItemsHost="true"
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" />
                        <Border
                            x:Name="contentPanel"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                Margin="0"
                                ContentSource="SelectedContent"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                            <Setter TargetName="headerPanel" Property="Grid.Row" Value="1" />
                            <Setter TargetName="contentPanel" Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="RowDefinition0" Property="Height" Value="*" />
                            <Setter TargetName="RowDefinition1" Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                            <Setter TargetName="headerPanel" Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                            <Setter TargetName="headerPanel" Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="contentPanel" Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="headerPanel" Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="contentPanel" Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Property="Width" Value="*" />
                            <Setter TargetName="RowDefinition0" Property="Height" Value="*" />
                            <Setter TargetName="RowDefinition1" Property="Height" Value="0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="headerPanel" Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="headerPanel" Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
                            <Setter TargetName="headerPanel" Property="LayoutTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                            <Setter TargetName="headerPanel" Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="contentPanel" Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="headerPanel" Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
                            <Setter TargetName="contentPanel" Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Property="Width" Value="*" />
                            <Setter TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                            <Setter TargetName="RowDefinition0" Property="Height" Value="*" />
                            <Setter TargetName="RowDefinition1" Property="Height" Value="0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="headerPanel" Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="headerPanel" Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
                            <Setter TargetName="headerPanel" Property="LayoutTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="VoidwalkerTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root">
                        <Border
                            x:Name="Border"
                            Margin="0"
                            Background="Yellow"
                            BorderBrush="Red"
                            BorderThickness="1,1,1,0"
                            CornerRadius="1,1,0,0">
                            <TextBlock
                                x:Name="ContentSite"
                                Margin="12,2,12,2"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger SourceName="ContentSite" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource GlobalAccentSolidColorBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#444444" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#444444" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#eeeeee" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#a4a4a4" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#373737" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#2b2b2b" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CornerRadius` is wrong when [`TabStripPlacement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tabitem.tabstripplacement?view=netcore-3.1) is set to `Bottom`. The reason for this is that the header panel is not rotated in that case, because the content would be displayed upside-down then.

You can add a trigger to the `TabItem` control template, which flips the corner radius depending on that. The [`TabStripPlacement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tabitem.tabstripplacement?view=netcore-3.1) property is available on both `TabControl` and `TabItem`.

```
<Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="{x:Static Dock.Bottom}">
   <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,1,1"/>
</Trigger>
```

An alternative to this is to rotate the `Border` 180° so that the corner radius is correct and then rotate its `ContentSite` by 180° so that its rotation is reversed and it is *not* displayed upside-down.

```
<Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
   <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="LayoutTransform">
      <Setter.Value>
         <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="LayoutTransform">
      <Setter.Value>
         <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

Paste any of the two alternative triggers into the `TabItem` control template `Triggers` section.